# Multiple Dex files running in tablet

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

I have tested my application in both Note3 and Samsung Galaxy S6 and it runs without any problems. I get a message saying "To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap", which i don't believe to be a problem. Once I try to run it in a Samsung GT (tablet) running Android 4.2.2 I get the following errors:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: 
Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;"
,"sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

And some other errors come after it. I've looked through the web but I can't find a way to solve my problem.

I would have pasted my gradles here but since my application runs without problem in smartphones and I have a project with four more modules I don't think I should post it here for now. I will if someone finds it necessary.

For an additional information, I recently migrated this project from eclipse to Android Studio.

Comment: Are you compiling the v4 support jar as well as including it via some other Gradle dependency like the v7 support library?

Comment: I have v13 in one module and v4 in other module

Comment: On the right-side of Android Studio, there should be a Gradle window that you can open and inspect the dependency tree by finding the "dependencies" task. Or, if you are comfortable in the terminal, `./gradlew app:dependencies` at the project root (assuming `app` is the parent module)

Comment: But my app runs in smartphones and not in the tablet. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm only including the v4 library now and yet i get the same problem. I only call it once, i tried to exclude 'support-v4' from every include i have, i removed the v13 jar from my libs folder and still the same error